# Criar uma tabela de frequência baseado em outra coluna em Python

Tags: python

Boa tarde, pessoal.

Tenho um conjunto de dados em um arquivo .csv, contendo duas colunas: tweets e classificação, em que 'tweets' corresponde a um tweet qualquer buscado no twitter e 'classificação' corresponde a 'positivo' ou 'negativo'.

Desejo, então, fazer uma tabela de frequência, palavra por palavra, em que cada linha contenha uma palavra não repetida e a classificação desta palavra na frase.

Bom, o numpy ou o nltk tem alguma função que faça isso?

Eu estou tentando fazer dois laços, um para percorrer as linhas e outro para percorrer palavra a palvra, mas não estou sabendo qual estrutura de dados utilizar para fazer essa tabela de frequência ou como o algorítmo ficaria.

Até o momento tenho isso:

```
    import nltk
import pandas as pd
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from string import punctuation
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
import numpy as np

#lê o arquivo
dataset = pd.read_csv('tweets.csv')

#busca as stop_words em português e remove a palavra 'não' para não causar contradições
stopwords = set(stopwords.words('portuguese') + list(punctuation))
stopwords = {x for i,x in enumerate(stopwords) if x != 'não'}

#busca o que são tweets e o que são classes
tweets = dataset['Text'].values
classes = dataset['Classificacao'].values

for tweet in tweets:
    for palavra in tweet:
        print(palavra)
```

Da maneira que está, era para o algorítmo printar palavra por palavra, mas está printando letra a letra, e não estou entendendo o porque disso.

Sei que ainda não é o que eu desejo, mas é o começo.

Qualquer ajuda seria bem-vinda, obrigado.

Comment: Sua "tabela de frequência" será calculada individualmente para cada `tweet` ou seria uma única tabela para todos os `tweets` ?

Comment: Uma tabela única para todos os tweets, contendo todas as palavras de todos os tweets juntos.

Answer (score 1):

Essa tabela que você pretende calcular se chama [Histograma](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histograma).

Segue um código capaz de calcular um Histograma a partir de um arquivo `.CSV`:

```
import csv
import string
from collections import Counter

palavras = []

with open('tweets.csv' ) as arqcsv:
    leitor = csv.reader( arqcsv, delimiter=';')
    for linha in leitor:
        palavras += [ palavra.strip( string.punctuation ) for palavra in linha[0].lower().split() ]

cnt = Counter( palavras )

for palavra, frequencia in sorted(cnt.items(), key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True):
    print( '{} : {}'.format(palavra,frequencia) )
```

Arquivo de testes (`tweets.csv`):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.;Positivo
Pellentesque scelerisque odio rutrum nunc facilisis convallis.;Positivo
Maecenas luctus luctus purus interdum venenatis.;Positivo
Nulla elementum id purus nec interdum.;Positivo
Sed malesuada nec est id convallis.;Positivo
Vivamus non facilisis mauris.;Negativo
Nullam lacinia massa libero, in vulputate nisi faucibus et.;Negativo
Mauris maximus justo vel suscipit consequat.;Negativo
Morbi sit amet neque rutrum, semper ante aliquam, egestas enim.;Positivo
Integer eget mauris faucibus, efficitur odio nec, accumsan justo.;Positivo
Sed tristique felis risus, quis tristique dolor tempor ut.;Positivo
Etiam vel magna augue.;Negativo
Quisque blandit, elit nec sollicitudin rhoncus, lectus congue lacus.;Positivo
Donec sit amet enim vel leo gravida malesuada vitae sed tortor.;Positivo
Morbi in maximus ex, vitae pharetra tellus.;Negativo
Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.;Positivo
Nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam at felis pharetra, porta risus sed.;Negativo
```

Saída:

```
nec : 4
sed : 4
mauris : 3
vel : 3
sit : 3
amet : 3
risus : 2
interdum : 2
justo : 2
purus : 2
in : 2
dolor : 2
et : 2
etiam : 2
id : 2
felis : 2
facilisis : 2
pharetra : 2
rutrum : 2
elit : 2
tristique : 2
vitae : 2
malesuada : 2
maximus : 2
faucibus : 2
morbi : 2
enim : 2
odio : 2
convallis : 2
luctus : 2
ipsum : 1
leo : 1
efficitur : 1
augue : 1
vivamus : 1
orci : 1
maecenas : 1
ut : 1
donec : 1
semper : 1
nunc : 1
ante : 1
ex : 1
tellus : 1
egestas : 1
massa : 1
aliquam : 1
gravida : 1
porta : 1
magna : 1
pellentesque : 1
nulla : 1
quisque : 1
parturient : 1
mus : 1
rhoncus : 1
scelerisque : 1
consectetur : 1
sollicitudin : 1
at : 1
suscipit : 1
non : 1
blandit : 1
est : 1
accumsan : 1
nisi : 1
adipiscing : 1
magnis : 1
varius : 1
natoque : 1
consequat : 1
ridiculus : 1
eget : 1
elementum : 1
montes : 1
integer : 1
libero : 1
lacinia : 1
neque : 1
tempor : 1
nullam : 1
dis : 1
vulputate : 1
lectus : 1
nascetur : 1
venenatis : 1
tortor : 1
quis : 1
penatibus : 1
lorem : 1
lacus : 1
congue : 1
```

Comment: Obrigado @Lacobus. Pelo que eu vi, a saída conta as palavras que são distintas. O que eu gostaria era de que para cada palavra distinta, contasse o número de vezes positivas e negativas que elas aparecem no dataset. Ex: lorem {positivas: 2, negativas : 8}. Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso? Ainda é histograma?

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do @Lacobus, para saber a classificação de cada palavra, você pode separar os positivos e negativos da seguinte forma:

```
import csv
import string
from collections import Counter

palavras = []
positivo = []
negativo = []

with open('tweets.csv' ) as arqcsv:
    leitor = csv.reader( arqcsv, delimiter=';')
    for linha in leitor:
        plinha = [palavra.strip( string.punctuation ) for palavra in linha[0].lower().split()]
        palavras += plinha
        if(linha[1].lower() == 'positivo'):
            positivo += plinha
        else:
            negativo += plinha

cntPalavras = Counter(palavras)
cntPositivo = Counter(positivo)
cntNegativo = Counter(negativo)


for palavra, frequencia in sorted(cntPalavras.items(), key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True):
    pos = cntPositivo[palavra]
    neg = cntNegativo[palavra]
    print( '{} : [ f: {}, p: {}, n: {} ]'.format(palavra,frequencia, pos, neg) )
```

Utilizando o mesmo arquivo csv de teste, irá resultar na seguinte saída:

```
nec: [f: 4, p: 4, n: 0]
sed: [f: 4, p: 3, n: 1]
sit: [f: 3, p: 3, n: 0]
amet: [f: 3, p: 3, n: 0]
mauris: [f: 3, p: 1, n: 2]
vel: [f: 3, p: 1, n: 2]
dolor: [f: 2, p: 2, n: 0]
elit: [f: 2, p: 2, n: 0]
odio: [f: 2, p: 2, n: 0]
rutrum: [f: 2, p: 2, n: 0]
facilisis: [f: 2, p: 1, n: 1]
convallis: [f: 2, p: 2, n: 0]
luctus: [f: 2, p: 2, n: 0]
purus: [f: 2, p: 2, n: 0]
interdum: [f: 2, p: 2, n: 0]
id: [f: 2, p: 2, n: 0]
malesuada: [f: 2, p: 2, n: 0]
in: [f: 2, p: 0, n: 2]
faucibus: [f: 2, p: 1, n: 1]
et: [f: 2, p: 1, n: 1]
maximus: [f: 2, p: 0, n: 2]
justo: [f: 2, p: 1, n: 1]
morbi: [f: 2, p: 1, n: 1]
enim: [f: 2, p: 2, n: 0]
tristique: [f: 2, p: 2, n: 0]
felis: [f: 2, p: 1, n: 1]
risus: [f: 2, p: 1, n: 1]
etiam: [f: 2, p: 0, n: 2]
vitae: [f: 2, p: 1, n: 1]
pharetra: [f: 2, p: 0, n: 2]
lorem: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
ipsum: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
consectetur: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
adipiscing: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
pellentesque: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
scelerisque: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
nunc: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
maecenas: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
venenatis: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
nulla: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
elementum: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
est: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
vivamus: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
non: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
nullam: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
lacinia: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
massa: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
libero: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
vulputate: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
nisi: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
suscipit: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
consequat: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
neque: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
semper: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
ante: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
aliquam: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
egestas: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
integer: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
eget: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
efficitur: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
accumsan: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
quis: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
tempor: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
ut: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
magna: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
augue: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
quisque: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
blandit: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
sollicitudin: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
rhoncus: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
lectus: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
congue: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
lacus: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
donec: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
leo: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
gravida: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
tortor: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
ex: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
tellus: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
orci: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
varius: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
natoque: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
penatibus: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
magnis: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
dis: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
parturient: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
montes: [f: 1, p: 1, n: 0]
nascetur: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
ridiculus: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
mus: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
at: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
porta: [f: 1, p: 0, n: 1]
```